# Visualization of Steps during Optimization CPLEX

Tags: optimization, constraints, cplex

I have a problem within my optimization an don´t know what might be the root of the problem. I only know that there is conflict between two constraints. Therefore it goes with the relaxation, but I need an optimal solution...
So I would like to see what CPLEX does. In detail: There is the following constraint:

```
forall(i in B)
    Constraint3: sum(<i,j,w_i,w_j> in arcs)x[<i,j,w_i,w_j>]==1;
```

I would like to see the arcs it uses within the optimization process, so e.g.:

```
<1,2,5,8> <2,8,4,9> <8,12,1,12>...
```

How can I do this? Is that even possible? :)

Thank you very much in advande

Sincerely

Comment: I don't think this is a very useful procedure to debug models. Maybe you can tell what the problem is.

Comment: I looked at that question. It is difficult to read. In general, you can dynamically enable or disable an arc by using a binary variable that indicates whether there can be a flow along the arc. Use a big-M constraint or maybe easier an indicator constraint.

Comment: IMHO Integer infeasible models are easiest debugged by using a small data set and fixing a known feasible solution (does not have to be optimal).